# UPDATE prepared statement executed without errors but table not getting updated

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm inserting data into a table and then updating some fields which values where not inserted. The code works without any errors but fields don't get updated.

Here is my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE my_table SET   field1=?, 
                                                field2=?,
                                                field3=?,
                                                field4=?,
                                                field5=?,
                                                field6=?,
                                                field7=?,
                                                field8=?,
                                                field9=?,
                                                field10=?,
                                                field11=?,
                                                field12=?,
                                                field13=?,
                                                updateTime=now()
                         WHERE id=?"); 

$stmt->bind_param('isssssssssssss', $info['x'],
                                    $info['x2'],
                                    $info['x3'],
                                    $info['x4'],
                                    $info['x5'],
                                    $info['x6'],
                                    $info['x7'],
                                    $info['x8'],
                                    $info['x9'],
                                    $info['x10'],
                                    $info['x11'],
                                    $info['12'],
                                    $info['x13'],
                                    $_GET['id']);

$stmt->execute();
```

Columns and variables' names have been changed but on the original code, they match existing columns.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? Have you checked the return status of `$stmt->execute()` or looked at `$stmt->error`?

Comment: Mike, yes, I have checked and there aren't errors. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the id matches one in the db?

Comment: Are you sure the column types are right in the first argument to `bind_param`? Usually ID is an integer.

Comment: @Barmar I changed it and now it binds an integer but isn't working either. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there's a typo somewhere. We obviously can't tell this from the question, since you renamed everything.

Comment: @Barmar but if there was a typo, there would probably be an error.

Comment: @HarryCallahan I agree, I'm grasping at straws. There's obviously some mistake in the code, UPDATE queries don't just get ignored for no reason. But since you haven't posted the actual code, it's hard for us to tell what it is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that the user is not showing us because he has not shown us the code actually being tried.

Answer (score 2):

## A complete check-list for solving any mysqli update problem

1. set **error reporting** for mysqli:

   ```
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   ```

   (add this line **once**, right before mysqli_connect)
2. and for PHP as well

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```
3. **if** there was certainly no errors, then

   - either there was to rows to match WHERE clasue
   - or all the fields already have been updated
4. if you think above items are out of question - then some sort of typo-like error to blame. Like you are editing wrong script, checking wrong database etc. Double-check everything. Then again.

Answer (score 0):

I see a

```
  $info['12'],
```

in your next-to-last bind.

Aside from that, it's going to be impossible for us to definitively find an error because you haven't shown us the code that you actually tried to execute.

Answer (score -1):

i don't understand you very well but you can try this code

```
$updateinfo = $mysqli->query("Update setting SET
field1='$field1', 
field2='$field2'
");
```